# How efficient can Azure BLOB Table service can be?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

How efficient azure blob tables can be?

Azure BLOB service has various components like Containers, Queues and Tables too. How efficient can tables be, what is their exact use case and why are they generally used with a supporting service like Azure CosmoDB.

Can anyone help me understand the concept and thought behind it?

**Edit:** The problem I am facing is that I have to log a processing batch of 700 000 data rows in C#, into BLOB Tables. How do I achieve this in the best practices?

Comment: As it stands now the question is pretty broad and will more than likely be closed. Please edit your question and include specific problem you're facing. There's plenty documentation available on Microsoft's website regarding Azure Storage and Cosmos DB services that you can refer to in order to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have edited the answer to include my specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for providing more information. Unfortunately it is still quite vague. Please provide more details. Also, there's no such thing as "BLOB Tables". There are blobs and then there are tables. These are two separate components of Azure Storage Service. I would suggest you first read more about these.

Comment: Efficiënt in terms of what? Costs? Performance? Ease of use?

Comment: @PeterBons Cost and performance are major concerns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a three in one question :-)

**How efficient can tables be**
Very efficient, if used properly. Every row in a table has a PartitionKey and Rowkey. When querying data it performs very well if you can reduce the set by using (parts of) the PartitionKey and RowKey. As soon as you start filtering on other columns performance can decrease very fast. See also [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/designing-a-scalable-partitioning-strategy-for-azure-table-storage) regarding this topic.

**what is their exact use case**
It is basically a key/value pair nosql solution. It can be used very efficient to store simple data in a fast and cheap manner. It is one of the cheapest options when it comes to data storage. Tables don't have a fixed schema (hence, nosql) and is used to store for example logs, configuration data and simple data structures.

**and why are they generally used with a supporting service like Azure CosmosDB.**
This is not the case. Azure Table Storage can be used on its own. CosmosDB has a Table API that lets you make uses of CosmosDB against code written for Azure Table Storage without code modifications. It allows for premium performance as not only the PartitionKey and Rowkey are indexed, but all the other columns as well. So as soon as you start filtering on other columns performance will still be very good. But it will costs you more in terms of money.

Data storage could be best done using batches as data is written per partition. See the answer of Ivan.

Some more material on when to use it:
https://markheath.net/post/azure-tables-what-are-they-good-for

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2013/01/13/knowing-when-to-choose-windows-azure-table-storage-or-windows-azure-sql-database/